# Sharing variables - objective-c

Tags: objective-c

Here is my code:

```
PtyView *v = [[PtyView alloc] init];
[v sendData([charlieImputText stringValue])];
```

in the PtyView.m file I have this:

```
void sendData(NSString *data) {
NSRunAlertPanel(@"",data,@"",@"",@""); //used for testing
}
```

But for some reason, the code errors: saying that PtyView may not respond to sendData, and I know that the code is incorrect. How would I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sendData is not written in objective-C; it is a C primitive function. You should write a method in Obj-C like:

```
- (void) sendData: (NSString *)data {
  NSRunAlertPanel(@"",data,@"",@"",@"");
}
```

Comment: I get this error with the first code snippet as well, I'm not accessing it correctly: expected ']' before '(' token.

Comment: Correct it to [v sendData:[charlieImputText stringValue]]; and read an introduction to the objective-c language.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Anders has said, even if sendData were properly implemented as a method, it is not being called correctly. The correct invocation syntax would be

```
[v sendData: [charlieImputText stringValue]];
```

More information about Objective-C methods can be found in [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW5).

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are importing "PtyView.h" into the file you are using it in.